# =IF(test,mot,"?") ¿Cómo puedo saber lo que se esconde detrás de la prueba lógica test en Excel?

Tags: excel, condiciones, google-hoja-de-cálculo, lógica, xls

Gengo un xlsx en spreadsheet y hay una celda con una expression `=IF(test,mot,"?")`. Me gustaria saber que esta escondido en la expresion logica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté convertirlo en un Google Sheet y dar un visatzo a los scripts de Google pero no habia ninguna cosa.

[Aqui esta un vinculo al xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p-urDsPkRyv4ULFTX0XHB4l6i9-nYPXY/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100143345999442003446&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IF(test,mot,"?")` es simplemente un uso de [la expresión `IF()` de Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), lo que se evalúa es:

- ¿Es `true` lo que hay en `test`?
- Si lo es, muestra en esta celda lo que hay en `mot`
- De lo contrario, muestra el carácter `?`

PERO, ¿qué hay en `test` y qué hay en `mot`? Pues ambos son *Intervalos con nombre* (no sé si se llaman así también en Excel). Son celdas o intervalos a los que has dado un nombre.

Si te colocas en la celda `E2` (donde está el signo de interrogación en rojo) verás que en la parte superior izquierda, encima del `1`, aparecerá un dropdown mostrando la palabra `secret`. Significa que en esa celda (`E2`) hay definido un *Intervalo de nombre* que se llama `secret`, y si despliegas el dropdown verás todos tus intervalos con nombre, en qué hoja están y en qué celda. Ahí verás que tienes un intervalo llamado `mot` que está en la celda `B59` de la hoja `Bilan`, otro llamado `test` que está en la celda `A59` de la hoja `Bilan`, etc.

PERO, *"no veo ni la celda `A59` ni la `B59` en la hoja"*. Pues no, no las ves porque están ocultas, pero existen y deberían tener valores.

Aquí te dejo una captura de pantalla donde puedes ver los *Intervalos con nombre* desplegados y la derecha la `Hoja!Celda` en que están.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]